# how to modify the width of search container column text?

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-6

how to modify the width of search container column text?

I want to change the width of the `<th>` table.

I used the attribute **cssClass** of `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>` liferay taglib but I did not work for me.

Table header:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVhYV.png)

view.jsp:

```
    <liferay-ui:search-container orderByCol="<%=sortByCol%>"
     orderByType="<%=sortByType%>" iteratorURL="<%=url%>"
     delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-result">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
      <% //some code %>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="file"
                            className="DLFileEntry">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Val1"
                                    cssClass="txt-capitalize width-11" value="<%=value1%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Val2"
                                    cssClass="txt-capitalize width-11" value="<%=value2%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Val3"
                                    cssClass="txt-capitalize width-11" value="<%=value3%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Value4"
                                    cssClass="txt-capitalize width-11" value="<%=value4%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Val5"
                                    cssClass="txt-capitalize width-11" value="<%=value5%>" />
<!-- some other search-container-column-text -->
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator
        searchContainer="<%= searchContainer %>"
        paginate="${fn:length(listFiles) ge 10}" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

main.css:

```
.width-11{
    width:11%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 0;

}
```

#### Update

If I inspect the code in the browser we can see the css class that exist.

[inspect table row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibecu.png)

Comment: is that because of the content of the actual table cells? In that case welcome to CSS-hell. Use your browser's developer tools to see if your width and padding is actually applied

Answer (score 0):

You need to distribute width % properly so that it aggregate to 100%;

width: 11% would be only 55% (as there are 5 column in your table) and remaing 45% will be evenly distributed.

Comment: there is some other search-container-column-text, check the code again. I mentioned this in the comment in the code.

Comment: I think the problem with the table content.
if I have a large image, the width of the column will be changed.
and if I have a text with several words he does not return to the line.

Comment: you can set style="max-width:100%; width:100%" for image tag and try.

Comment: If I put a large image is it going to change the size of the table column?

Comment: yes, image act differently in table as table is set display: table; so give it restriction to occupy only available space in column using max-width.

Comment: and for the text I want it to return to the line if it exceeds the size of the table column.

Comment: use <p></p> or <div style="display:inline"></div>

Comment: Itried `<p></p>` and `<div style="display:inline"></div>` and did not work. The column size text is 16%, the text does not return to the line.

Comment: the text return to line if they are small words separated by spaces.
but if there are long words it does not return to the line.